# Plugin OSGI partially reexport

Tags: java, osgi

Is that possible to reexport only part of a dependency plugin?

I mean ...

Plugin_1 has 3 exported packages

```
com.p1
com.p2
com.p3
```

When I reexport Plugin_1 I don't wanna reexport the package "com.p2". Is there some way to do that?

*It is important to say that Plugin_1 cannot be changed!

Why this:
Plugin_1 is a legacy plugin that cannot be touched. It has bunches of classes that I wanna provide through a single brand new plugin (e.g: Plugin_New) with reexport OSGI feature, but some of these reexported classes (the ones on "com.p2" package ) should be hidden cause I wanna clients using the new classes I just create on the new plugin. Plugin_1 code refactoring is out of question cause it still being used by other systems.

Comment: I recommend not re-exporting any packages at all.

Comment: What do you mean Neil? If I do no reexport any package, what else can I do?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but there is simply no need to reexport packages in OSGi. So you need to clarify why you think it is necessary.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the main reason I wanna do that. I hope it helps to clarify my reasons to do that, even they are not strong enough  :)

Answer (score 4):

In OSGi, re-export is a concept or Require-Bundle. Require-bundle is in almost all cases a `really bad idea`.

If you you just use Package-Imports and -Exports then any problem you might have in this area magically disappears. :-)

Comment: Peter, I'm not sure if I understood what you meant. Can you give me an example of using pkg import & export you just mentioned that would 'solve" my issue?

Comment: **ANY** book or basic tutorial on OSGi will give you this information. Package importing is the fundamental mechanism for creating dependencies in OSGi.

Comment: How is it a bad idea to be in control of where the dependency comes from?

Comment: Once you go down that rabbit hole your code will become significantly more complex because lots of different parties in your final product want to control the whole. In general, you want to make your code as uncoupled of the whole as possible. This allows you to manage dependencies in one place and allows you to reuse components in other contexts.